# How can I place links at the bottom of the site?

Tags: menu

is it possible to place my privacy notice and cookies policy in the footer menu?  Is there one and how do I do it?

Comment: I recommend you to hire someone. It doesn't sound like you are familiar with HTML or PHP at all so you are going to have a hard time if you want to finish it until tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to give step-by-step instructions since every Craft site is unique and built differently.

The front-end templates for your site live in the `craft/templates` folder on your server.  You can change the look and layout of your site by editing those files, which are a combination of Twig and HTML.  Thanks like JavaScript, CSS files, images and assets will typically live in your site's public HTML folder.

Here's a list of learning resources to help get you up to speed on Craft and some links at the end in case you need help finding a developer.

**Craft Official Docs & Support**

- [Craft CMS docs](https://craftcms.com/docs) - The official Craft CMS documentation
- [Craft Slack group](https://craftcms.com/community#slack) - The Craft development team is in Slack every day along with 6,000+ other Craft developers and users from all over the world.
- [Craft Stack Exchange](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com) - You obviously found this one, but it is generally the best place to ask "how do I" type questions.
- Official support email at support@craftcms.com

**Learn Craft**

- [Mijingo Craft Tutorials](http://mijingo.com/craft) - Mijingo is our official education and training partner. They have a number of excellent free and paid resources for Craft CMS & Craft Commerce. Ryan Irelan, Mijingo's founder, also offers customized training online or on-site.
- [Tuts+ Tutorials](https://tutsplus.com/courses/search/Craft+CMS) - Not official but very good and low cost (most are $9).

**Professional Services**

- [Partner Match](https://craftcms.com/partners) - If you need implementation help for Craft, we can match you with one of our Craft Service Partners or Craft Experts. We work with enterprise level partners, freelancers, and everyone in between.